# Concourse: vars vs params

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse, concourse-pipeline

Concourse provides two concepts: vars and params. Both of them can be used to pass some values inside of a task.

```
      params:
        COMMAND: deployment.deploy
      vars:
        command: deployment.deploy
```

When should use params? is there any rule of thumb?

Answer (score 3):

`params` are an optional configuration of the task schema. [tasks#params](https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html#schema.task.params)

> A key-value mapping of string keys and values that are exposed to the task via environment variables.

```yaml
task: env
config:
  platform: linux
  image_resource:
    type: registry-image
    source:
      repository: alpine
  params:
    VALUE: something
  run:
    path: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - echo $VALUE
```

`vars` can be used in most parts of the task configuration. [vars](https://concourse-ci.org/vars.html#var-interpolation)

> Aside from credentials, vars may also be used for generic parameterization of pipeline configuration templates, allowing a single pipeline config file to be configured multiple times with different parameters - e.g. ((branch_name)).

```yaml
task: env
config:
  platform: linux
  image_resource:
    type: registry-image
    source:
      repository: my-image
      tag: ((branch_name))
  params:
    BRANCH_NAME: ((branch_name))
  run:
    path: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - echo $BRANCH_NAME; echo 'can also be interpolated here: ((branch_name))'
```